# LINQ to SQL: rows to columns

Tags: linq-to-sql

I would like to have a single LINQ to SQL query to count 2 entities from the same table. E.g. Count number of employees and managers from table Personnel.

Example:

```
var q = from p in db.Personnel
         where p.PersonType == 'Manager' || p.PersonType == 'Employee'
         select new
         {  NoOfPersonnel = p.Count(p => p.PersonType == 'Employee'), //Wrong way
            NoOfManagers = p.Count(p => p.PersonType == 'Manager')   //Wrong way
         }
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = from employee in db.Personnel
           where employee.PersonType == "Manager" || employee.PersonType == "Employee"
           group employee by employee.PersonType 
           into temp
           select new { PersonType = temp.Key, Count = temp.Count() };
```